# Javascript Vertical Array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have a javascript array where, for each iteration, a name is added to the end using the push feature. I'm sending this array to a html file where it will be displayed. Currently displaying this array after all iterations have completed gives:

> John, Smith, Paul, Doe

However, I wish the array to be displayed vertically like:

> John 
>  Smith 
>  Paul 
>  Doe

In Javascript, is there some way to specify for each name to be entered as a new row in the array? In Matlab you can easily specify which row or column you want data to be stored in the array but I am yet to find a simple approach in Javascript.

Thank you for any help you might be able to give me!

**UPDATE:**
Javascript (simplified):

```
port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
    var Array = []
    var Names = ["John", "Smith", "Paul", "Doe"]
    for (var p = 0; p < Names.length; p++) {
    Array.push(Names[p])
    }
    document.getElementById('status').textContent = Array;
});
```

HTML (simplified):

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="Javascript.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            body { 
                min-width       : 400px;
                min-height      : 300px;
                text-align      : right;
                background-color: #D0D0D0; }
            #status { 
                font-size       : 10px;
                color           : #0000CC;
                text-align      : left;
                font-family     : "Times New Roman", Times, serif; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="status"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Presentation is not handled by JavaScript. You can show your array however you want. It all depends on what is the output, like the console, or a webpage.

Comment: do you mean like array[3] = 'John' ?

Comment: The html / dom displays your list, not the JS array representaion. Add <br /> tags between items.

Comment: Please provide some code so we can help.

Comment: Yes, guergana, something like that.

Comment: Brandon - I'm passing this array to my html file so I'm unsure how to add break tags there. I've tried adding break and \n tags within Javascript but that doesn't work.

Comment: @MSTTm - post your js and html and I'll take a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To respect newlines in CSS you can use the `white-space` property. First `join` the items with newlines:

```
var array = ['one', 'two', 'three']
element.textContent = array.join('\n')
```

Then set the appropriate CSS:

```
element {
  white-space: pre
}
```

```js
var p = document.querySelector('p')

var array = ['one', 'two', 'three']

p.textContent = array.join('\n')
```

```css
p {
  white-space: pre
}
```

```html
<p></p>
```

Comment: Where, within the html file, are the <p> tags placed? In the body? And is the p{} section placed within the <style> section?

Answer (score 2):

Try utilizing `Array.prototype.forEach` to iterate array `arr` ,  create text node for each item within `arr` , append text node with "\n" concatenated to `pre` element.

```js
var arr = ["John", "Smith", "Paul", "Doe"];
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0];
arr.forEach(function(el, i) {
  elem.appendChild(
    document.createTextNode(el + "\n")
  )
})
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, do the <pre> tags go in the body section of the html file?

Comment: @MSTTm _"Just to clarify, do the <pre> tags go in the body section of the html file?"_ Yes.

Comment: So the body section should look like:
    <body>
    <div id="status"></div>
    <pre></pre>
    </body>

Comment: _"So the body section should look like: <body> <div id="status"></div> <pre></pre> </body>"_ Given `html` at Question , `js` at post above, try `<body> <pre id="status"></pre> </body>` . `css` defined within `style` element for `#status` should still be applied .

Comment: Thank you guys so much for your help. However, I'm getting a strange error:
"Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

```js
var names = ["John", "Smith", "Paul", "Doe"];
document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = names.join('<br>');
```

```html
<div id="out"></id>
```